# How to use threading in Scrapy/Twisted, i.e. how to do async calls to blocking code in response callbacks?

Tags: python, multithreading, scrapy, twisted

I need run some multi-thread\multiprocessing work (because I have some library which uses blocking call) in Scrapy, and after its completion put back Request to Scrapy engine.

I need something like this:

```
def blocking_call(self, html):
    # ....
    # do some work in blocking call
    return Request(url)

def parse(self, response):
    return self.blocking_call(response.body)
```

How I can do that? I think I should to use Twisted reactor and Deferred object.
But Scrapy `parse` callback must return only `None` or `Request` or `BaseItem` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to return a `Deferred` that fires after your blocking operation has finished running in one of the reactor's thread pool threads, use `deferToThreadPool`:

```
from twisted.internet.threads import deferToThreadPool
from twisted.internet import reactor

...

    def parse(self, response):
        return deferToThreadPool(
            reactor, reactor.getThreadPool(), self.blocking_call, response.body)
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on answer from @Jean-Paul Calderone I did some investigation and testing and here is what I have found out.

Internally scrapy uses [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) framework for managing request/response sync and async calls.

Scrapy spawns **requests** (crawling) in **async** manner, but processing **responses** (our custom parse callback functions) are done **synchronous**. So if you have blocking call in a callback, **it will block the whole engine**.

Hopefully this can be changed. When processing [Deferred](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.1/core/howto/gendefer.html#what-deferreds-don-t-do-make-your-code-asynchronous) response callback result, Twisted handles the case [(twisted.internet.defer.Deferred source)](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/internet/defer.py#L603) if *Deferred* object returns other *Deferred* object. In that case Twisted yields new async call.

Basically, if **we return [Deferred](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.1/core/howto/gendefer.html#what-deferreds-don-t-do-make-your-code-asynchronous) object from our response callback**, this will change nature of response callback call **from sync to async**. For that we can use method [deferToThread](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.1/core/howto/gendefer.html#integrating-blocking-code-with-twisted) ( [internally calls](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/internet/threads.py#L58) `deferToThreadPool(reactor, reactor.getThreadPool()...` - which was used in @Jean-Paul Calderone code example).

The working code example is:

```
from twisted.internet.threads import deferToThread
from twisted.internet import reactor

class SpiderWithBlocking(...):
    ...
    def parse(self, response):
        return deferToThread(reactor, self.blocking_call, response.body)

    def blocking_call(self, html):
        # ....
        # do some work in blocking call
        return Request(url)
```

Additionally, only callbacks can return Deferred objects, but `start_requests` can not (scrapy logic).