# Using Deferred in Scrapy downloadermiddleware

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

I'm going to use some blocking code(this waiting for free proxy) in Scrapy downloadermiddleware.
I was going to use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842469/how-to-use-threading-in-scrapy-twisted)

But it's realy doesn't work in downloadermiddleware, because the method `process_request(self, request, spider)` waiting for `isinstance(response, (Response, Request))`

How best to do this?

Comment: That blocking call is going to change the request?

Comment: @nramirezuy, yes, it's should change meta of the request.

Comment: What does your blocking code need to do, specifically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use twisted method "deferToThread" to run the blocking code without blocking the MainThread

```py
from twisted.internet.threads import deferToThread

class DownloaderMiddleware:    
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        return deferToThread(self.run_blocking_code_in_diffrent_thread, request, spider)

    def run_blocking_code_in_diffrent_thread(self,request, spider) -> HtmlResponse:
        print("Code will block here on a diffrent thread and wont stop MainThread")
        request.meta["proxy"] = get_proxy_blocking_call()
        return request
```